# Difference between 'Can I help you with' and 'Can I help you'

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between 'Can I help you with' and 'Can I help you'?

please teach me how they are different.

Comment: It's not syntactically valid to end your utterance with the preposition ***with*** (it must refer to *something* - a noun, pronoun, demonstrative, or similar, such as *Can I help you **with that**?*). Valid prepositions that can stand alone include *Can I help you **out**?* (implied metaphorical *...out of your problematical situation*) and *Can I help you **up**?* (implied literal *...up from your low seating position*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Can I help you?*** is an "open-ended" question; it does not place any explicit limitations on what help the person being asked may request. There may be implicit limitations imposed by context; for example, a store employee approaching you while you are looking at the counter they are responsible for may ask the open-ended *Can I help you?*, but is really only inquiring if you need assistance with the products being sold at that counter.

***Can I help you with {whatever}?*** is a limiting question; the person asking is explicitly specifying that their willingness or ability to assist is limited to *{whatever}*.